# Compile node module with node-gyp for a specific NODE_MODULE_VERSION

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-gyp

I am trying to use an npm package `fsuipc` in an electron app. However, when I start the app I get the following error

```
The module 'node_modules\fsuipc\build\Release\fsuipc.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 98.
```

I am trying to recompile it for version 98. I have 0 experience with node-gyp or similar, I just want it to work :(. I have tried doing `node-gyp build --target=v16.13.1` but it still compiles to this mysterious version 93 which I can't seem to change. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of research and endless trial and error I have found a solution.

This may have been an error in the electron boiler plate that I was using but the bottom line is that I had to manually build the native package. From [here](https://github.com/electron/node-abi/blob/main/abi_registry.json) I learned that I was compiling it using my current node.js version installed but because I was using electron it required building the module with electron headers. The steps I followed were these:

1. `cd release/app && npm install fsuipc` Native dependencies have to be installed in release/app.
2. `cd node_modules/fsuipc && npm install` Move to the package dir and install its required dependencies for building.
3. `node-gyp rebuild --target=15.3.5 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers` This was the key. The target has to be the VALID and FULL version name that you are using from [this website](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable) (if you are using electron). From trial and error I solved some problems by specifying that I was building for x64. And in order for it to compile using electron specify the headers url (same for all electron versions).
4. `cd ../../ && npm install` By calling install in the release/app directory the modules are linked with the "normal" node_modules

Then just run!

Comment: I have quite a similar problem, although you answer doesn't solve the issue for me. I have an Electron 25 app and I'm compiling a module for it. When running I get the same NODE_MODULE_VERSION mismatch version altough versions are `115` vs `116`. I figured out that 115 corresponds to Node 20.9.0, but I can't a version that'd give me 116.

Comment: Actually, your answer is 100% correct. I just omitted `--target=25.9.3 --arch=x64` for some reason when calling `gyp` for the first time.